# How can I make grep print the lines below and above each matching line?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to search each line for the word `FAILED`, then print the line above and below each matching line, as well as the matching line.

---

Input:

```
id : 15
Status : SUCCESS
Message : no problem

id : 15
Status : FAILED
Message : connection error
```

Desired output for `grep 'FAILED'`:

```
id : 15
Status : FAILED
Message : connection error
```

Comment: Life's not fair. There is a better answer 6 minutes older, but because it's not accepted, it receives zero attention. Usually when given several equivalent answers, it's fair to accept the earliest one.

Answer (score 978, accepted):

grep's `-A 1` option will give you one line after; `-B 1` will give you one line before; and `-C 1` combines both to give you one line both before and after, `-1` does the same.

Comment: +1, I forgot about -C (lines of context)

Comment: @StevenLu, but only for the duration of `grep` so prepare a long input.

Comment: perfect for searching fasta for header and getting sequence (if it's a one-liner fasta)

Comment: You're a wizard

Comment: Me, patting myself on the back whenever I need to use one of these flags: "`-A` could stand for 'above' or 'after' and `-B` could stand for 'below' or 'before'. Hmm...clearly the most reasonable choice is 'above' and 'below' since that's how they appear on the screen, plus it makes sense alphabetically."

Answer (score 71):

Use -B, -A or -C option

```
grep --help
...
-B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
-A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
-C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
-NUM                      same as --context=NUM
...
```

Comment: Amusing that this is the output of `grep --help | grep context`

Answer (score 50):

Use -A and -B switches (mean lines-after and lines-before):

```
grep -A 1 -B 1 FAILED file.txt
```