# Integrate ClearCase with AzureDevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, clearcase

I am trying to enable the AzureDevOps for ESB- webmethods. The Code package is in ClearCase. Any scripting technique that anyone can suggest for pulling the code from ClearCase to Git(one time set up)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of ClearCase:

- base ClearCase, for which you have [some migration techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477051/6309), but imperfect)
- UCM (with their [full baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309)), where you have [other migration techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309ucm%20clearcase%20git)

In both case, I would recommend:

- import a few labels/baselines into a new Git repository
- keeping the ClearCase VOB in read-only mode,
- move on from there, allowing [Azure to work with git repositories](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/repos/)