# How to grep first match before match?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file where I basically need grep to return the "key" associated with a particular value.

For instance, if I have:

```
[abc]
field1=34234
field2=t2342

[def]
field1=44354
field2=23423
```

I want to be able to grep, say, 23423, and then basically match on `[def]` and return/print out the contents of the brackets (e.g. `def`).

The file is formatted something like this, where I want to match the first line containing `[` and `]` *before* the argument to grep, if that makes sense.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072643/how-can-i-make-grep-print-the-lines-below-and-above-each-matching-line), which is similar, where `-B 1` will give you the line before, and some variant of that can be used to prevent some number of lines before the match.

The problem is I can't count on the exact number of lines between the match and the first line with brackets before it, so I want to avoid doing that and simply match for the first line containing a bracket before.

Is this possible to do with grep, or a similar bash utility?

Comment: `awk -v RS= '/23423/{gsub(/[][]/, "", $1); print $1}' file`?

Comment: This is easy to do with `awk`. If the line matches the section heading format, assign it to a variable. If the line matches the search string, print the variable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you're going to give the answer, post it as a real answer, not a comment. But we prefer not to write code for them.

Comment: That looks like an INI file. This might be useful: [How to parse and convert ini file into bash array variables? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/345665/403609)

Comment: @wjandrea It's not an ini, it's a .conf file, but I'll look into these suggestions

Comment: @InterLinked From what I understand, .conf files can be in the INI format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading the paragraphs one by one and once a paragraph contains a searched value get the first field without `[` and `]`:

```
awk -v RS= '/23423/{gsub(/[][]/, "", $1); print $1}' file
```

Note that `[][]` matches `[` or `]`.

Or, get the first field with trimmed out `[` and `]`:

```
awk -v RS= '/23423/{print substr($1, 2, length($1)-2)}' file
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/wKfPTG).

Comment: This works from the shell, but not when I call it from an external application. To exact errors are `[Nov 27 19:15:52] WARNING[3105][C-00002091]: pbx_variables.c:721 pbx_substitute_variables_helper_full: Error in extension logic (missing '}')
[Nov 27 19:15:52] WARNING[3105][C-00002091]: pbx_functions.c:462 func_args: Can't find trailing parenthesis for function 'SHELL(awk -v RS= '/text/{gsub(/[][]/, "", $1'?` I'm saving the SHELL output to a variable, so can I get rid of the $1 somehow and maybe simplify the expression? Removing print didn't fix it

Comment: You can't get rid of anything here, you need to adapt if for your app. Sometimes, doubling `$` helps, i.e. `$$1` (makefile usage). Not sure if one GNU `grep` will help, `grep -Poz -m1 '\[\K[^][]+(?=](?:\R.+)*23423)' file`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/iaVaIF).

Comment: I tried that in the shell and it doesn't work, not sure what the demo is doing

Comment: So, you are not using GNU grep then.

Comment: How would the awk work in a batch script? The input, 23423, is $1 (an argument), so that conflicts with the $1 in the awk statement

Comment: @InterLinked There is no conflict, the `$1` is inside single quotes.

Comment: There is a conflict, but I figured it out, it works in an external shell scritp

Comment: @InterLinked You could have added that detail to the question, it would be even more helpful.